# Delete Child Records with Missing Parent

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm attempting to create a SQL query to delete child records when the parent has been deleted.
The thing is, the children and parents are both stored in the same table.
Here's the (simplified) data model:

***ThingTable***

```
    ID  |  Name  | ParentID
   1000 | Thing1 |   NULL
   1001 | Thing2 |   1000
   1002 | Thing3 |   1000
   1003 | Thing4 |   1000
   1004 | Thing5 |   1003
```

***ChildThingTable***

```
    ID  |  Color  
   1001 |  Blue
   1002 |  Black
   1003 |  Green
   1004 |  Red
```

Assuming ID 1000 (the parent) was deleted, I'd need to delete the corresponding records from ChildThingTable as well as ThingTable.

My only restriction is that I cannot use a trigger or alter the underlying database structure in any way.

Here's my pseudocode that I've worked out, but I'm having difficulty translating it into SQL:

1. Delete from ChildThingTable where the matching record in ThingTable does not have a parent, based on ID and ParentID.
2. Delete from ThingTable where the matching record does not have a parent.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Common Table Expression to recurse the

```
-- Begin Create Test Data

SET NOCOUNT ON 

CREATE TABLE #ThingTable (
ID INT NOT NULL,
[Name] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
[ParentID] INT NULL

)


CREATE TABLE #ChildThingTable (
ID INT NOT NULL,
[Color] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,

)

INSERT INTO #ThingTable (ID,[Name],ParentID) VALUES (1000,'Thing1',NULL)
INSERT INTO #ThingTable (ID,[Name],ParentID) VALUES (1001,'Thing2',1000)
INSERT INTO #ThingTable (ID,[Name],ParentID) VALUES (1002,'Thing3',1000)
INSERT INTO #ThingTable (ID,[Name],ParentID) VALUES (1003,'Thing4',1000)
INSERT INTO #ThingTable (ID,[Name],ParentID) VALUES (1004,'Thing5',1003)

INSERT INTO #ChildThingTable ( ID, Color ) VALUES  ( 1001 , 'Blue')
INSERT INTO #ChildThingTable ( ID, Color ) VALUES  ( 1002 , 'Black')
INSERT INTO #ChildThingTable ( ID, Color ) VALUES  ( 1003 , 'Green')
INSERT INTO #ChildThingTable ( ID, Color ) VALUES  ( 1004 , 'Red')

SET NOCOUNT OFF
GO
-- End Create Test Data

-- This is a batch, but could easily be a stored procedure.  
DECLARE @InputID INT 
SET @InputID = 1000;

SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @Temp TABLE(ID INT NOT NULL);

WITH ThingCTE (ID, ParentID, [Level])
AS
(
SELECT tt1.ID, tt1.ParentID, 1 AS [Level]
FROM #ThingTable tt1
WHERE tt1.ID = @InputID
UNION ALL
SELECT tt2.ID, tt2.ParentID, tc1.[Level]+1
FROM #ThingTable tt2
JOIN ThingCTE tc1 ON (tt2.ParentID = tc1.ID)
)
INSERT INTO @Temp
        ( ID )
SELECT ID
FROM ThingCTE

SET NOCOUNT OFF

DELETE ctt
-- Output is for debug purposes, should be commented out in production.
OUTPUT Deleted.* 
FROM #ChildThingTable ctt
JOIN @Temp t ON (ctt.ID = t.ID);

DELETE tt 
-- Output is for debug purposes, should be commented out in production.
OUTPUT Deleted.* 
FROM #ThingTable tt
JOIN @Temp t ON (tt.ID = t.ID)

DROP TABLE #ChildThingTable;
DROP TABLE #ThingTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Does adding a constraint constitute 'alter the underlying database structure in any way'

Because I would consider using a constraint with a cascading Delete, This would require the Parent Id column to be a Foreign key to the ID table, then adding the constraint when you delete the primary key, the matching foreign key will be deleted too.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.T2
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_T1_T2_Cascade
FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES dbo.T1(EmployeeID) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

There is also recursive queries that can do similar things but I would start with this.

Then something like this should work
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL

```
DELETE
FROM thingtable START WITH ID = 1000
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = ParentID;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot add a constraint.  My only option is to use a stored procedure.  Thanks!

Comment: Added more, it might not be exactly right but it should be pretty close, and the link should help answer some questions.

Comment: The right way to handle RI is like @bowlturner posted. You can and will end up with bad data if you try to do this in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this procedure should do it ...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteThing 
    @IdToDelete INT
AS
BEGIN

    DELETE ChildThingTable
    WHERE ID IN ( SELECT ID FROM ThingTable WHERE ParentId = @IdToDelete );

    DELETE ChildThingTable
    WHERE ID = @IdToDelete;

    DELETE ThingTable
    WHERE ParentID = @IdToDelete;

    DELETE ThingTable
    WHERE ID = @IdToDelete;

END;
```

You might want to wrap this in a transaction so that the whole operation either succeeds or fails.

As others have mentioned, this is exactly the reason you should use referential integrity constructs (foreign keys).  They exist to help prevent invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

Try a recursive cte to climb all the way to the root, so each thing is displayed not just with the ParentID but with the parent's ParentID and so forth.

```
CREATE TABLE Things (
  ID INT NOT NULL,
  [Name] VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  [ParentID] INT NULL
);

INSERT INTO Things (ID,[Name],ParentID)
select 1000,'Thing1',NULL union all
select 1001,'Thing2',1000 union all
select 1002,'Thing3',1000 union all
select 1003,'Thing4',1002 union all
select 1004,'Thing5',1003;
```

Notice I've added a level to your data to show we can go all the way to the top, so Thing5's parent is Thing4, whose parent is Thing3, whose parent is Thing1.

```
with
Parents( ID, Name, ParentID, GrandParentID )
as(
  select t1.ID, t1.Name, t2.ID, t2.ParentID
    from Things t1
  left join Things t2
      on t2.id = t1.ParentID
  union all
  select t1.ID, t1.Name, p.ParentID, p.GrandParentID
    from Things t1
    join Parents p
      on p.ID = t1.ParentID
   where p.ParentID is not null or p.GrandParentID is not null
)
select ID, Name, ParentID
from Parents
order by ID, ParentID desc;
```

Which produces an output like this <kbd>[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9fc5a/2/0)</kbd>:

```
ID   NAME   PARENTID
==== ====== ========
1000 Thing1 (null)
1001 Thing2 1000
1002 Thing3 1000
1003 Thing4 1002
1003 Thing4 1000
1004 Thing5 1003
1004 Thing5 1002
1004 Thing5 1000
```

So if you deleted Thing3 (ID 1002), then also delete everything with 1002 in the ParentID column above (Thing4 and Thing5).

Deleting orphans from the child table is simple: do a left join back to the thing table and delete everything that doesn't find a match.

Answer (score 0):

I usually delete orphans from the child tables after the parent record was deleted.

```
DELETE T FROM ThingTable T WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM ParentTable WHERE Id=T.ParentTableId)
DELETE C FROM ChildThingTable C WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM ThingTable WHERE Id=C.ThingTableId)
```